# React importing image does not work for CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am having problems importing my image for CSS. I have imported the image as a test and it works when using it in the img tag using src={furnitureBG}.

I followed the docs and imported the image and then using the path as the value for url(''). However, no image renders and there is no error message.

I know the path is correct because when I use the code

```
<img src={furnitureBG} />
```

the image I desire renders. I am just wondering why this is not working on the following code for CSS background.

```
import furnitureBG from '../images/furniture-bg-7.png';

const Container = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.35), rgba(0,0,0,.35)), url('../images/furniture-bg-7.png');
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **url(${furnitureBG?.src})** in order to render image using styled component.

```js
   import furnitureBG from '../images/furniture-bg-7.png';

   const Container = styled.div`
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.35), rgba(0,0,0,.35)), url(${furnitureBG?.src});
   `
```

Comment: I had no idea that was an option! Thank you! I used  url(${furnitureBG}) and it is now rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `/images` folder into the `public` folder:

**App.js**

```js
const Container = styled.img`
  background-image: url("/images/asdf.png");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Directory structure:**

```
 - project
   - public
     - images
       - asdf.png
   - src
     - App.js
```